# Why does func Get of fasthttp in golang have `dst` parameter?

Tags: http, go, get

I found fasthttp godoc as fellow:

```
func Get
func Get(dst []byte, url string) (statusCode int, body []byte, err error)
Get appends url contents to dst and returns it as body.
The function follows redirects. Use Do* for manually handling redirects.
New body buffer is allocated if dst is nil.
```

But, when I run fellow code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    fh "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://www.okcoin.cn/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=btc_cny"

    dst := []byte("ok100")
    _, body, err := fh.Get(dst, url)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("body:", string(body))
    fmt.Println("dst:", string(dst))
}
```

**body** does not have "ok100", and **dst** is still "ok100".
why?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code where it is used in fasthttp's [client.go func  clientGetURLDeadlineFreeConn (line 672)](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/blob/master/client.go), you can see that if there is a timeout, dst's contents are copied to body at line 712. So based on what I read in the code (and debugged with Delve using your code), I saw that dst doesn't get updated in this usage. It seems that it can be used to provide default content to body in the event of a timeout - probably worth a direct question to fasthttp's author for more detail.

```
func clientGetURLDeadlineFreeConn(dst []byte, url string, deadline time.Time, c clientDoer) (statusCode int, body []byte, err error) {
timeout := -time.Since(deadline)
if timeout <= 0 {
    return 0, dst, ErrTimeout
}

var ch chan clientURLResponse
chv := clientURLResponseChPool.Get()
if chv == nil {
    chv = make(chan clientURLResponse, 1)
}
ch = chv.(chan clientURLResponse)

req := AcquireRequest()

// Note that the request continues execution on ErrTimeout until
// client-specific ReadTimeout exceeds. This helps limiting load
// on slow hosts by MaxConns* concurrent requests.
//
// Without this 'hack' the load on slow host could exceed MaxConns*
// concurrent requests, since timed out requests on client side
// usually continue execution on the host.
go func() {
    statusCodeCopy, bodyCopy, errCopy := doRequestFollowRedirects(req, dst, url, c)
    ch <- clientURLResponse{
        statusCode: statusCodeCopy,
        body:       bodyCopy,
        err:        errCopy,
    }
}()

tc := acquireTimer(timeout)
select {
case resp := <-ch:
    ReleaseRequest(req)
    clientURLResponseChPool.Put(chv)
    statusCode = resp.statusCode
    body = resp.body
    err = resp.err
case <-tc.C:
    body = dst
    err = ErrTimeout
}
releaseTimer(tc)

return statusCode, body, err
```

}

In [client.go func doRequestFollowRedirects (line 743)](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/blob/master/client.go) it is used at line 748: bodyBuf.B = dst

```
func doRequestFollowRedirects(req *Request, dst []byte, url string, c clientDoer) (statusCode int, body []byte, err error) {
resp := AcquireResponse()
bodyBuf := resp.bodyBuffer()
resp.keepBodyBuffer = true
oldBody := bodyBuf.B
bodyBuf.B = dst

redirectsCount := 0
for {
    req.parsedURI = false
    req.Header.host = req.Header.host[:0]
    req.SetRequestURI(url)

    if err = c.Do(req, resp); err != nil {
        break
    }
    statusCode = resp.Header.StatusCode()
    if statusCode != StatusMovedPermanently && statusCode != StatusFound && statusCode != StatusSeeOther {
        break
    }

    redirectsCount++
    if redirectsCount > maxRedirectsCount {
        err = errTooManyRedirects
        break
    }
    location := resp.Header.peek(strLocation)
    if len(location) == 0 {
        err = errMissingLocation
        break
    }
    url = getRedirectURL(url, location)
}

body = bodyBuf.B
bodyBuf.B = oldBody
resp.keepBodyBuffer = false
ReleaseResponse(resp)

return statusCode, body, err
```

}